# Ubuntu 18.04: Samsung SCX-3400 Scanner detected but not working

Tags: drivers, usb, scanner, sane

I am using the 64-bit 18.04 Ubuntu version. I have a Samsung SCX-3400 Multi-functional device. Printing works fine. Scanner does not. It's connected via USB.

The scanner used to work (roughly 4 years ago). Now it doesnt. I haven't used it in a while, so I cannot trace back the problem to a specific upgrade or similar.

I reinstalled the SANE tools and libs.

`sane-find-scanner` outputs

```
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04e8, product=0x344f [SCX-3400 Series]) at libusb:002:002 
 # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
 # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.
```

but

`scanimage -L` and sudo `scanimage -L` say that no scanners were identified.

I installed the uld package from the hp-driver-support (samsung doesn't host the drivers any longer but hp does). The libsane-smfp.so.1(.0(.1)) files are located in `/usr/lib64/sane/` (I also copied them to the `/usr/lib/sane/` directory)

`/etc/udev/rules.d/` contains `59-smfp_samsung.conf`, `70-snap.core.rules` and `70-snap.gimp.rules`

`59-smfp_samsung.conf` seems alright (idvendor 04e8 are referred to label end)

`/etc/sane.d/` contains `dll.conf`, `smpf-samsung.conf` `xerox_mfp.conf` `xerox_mfp-smfp.conf`:

content of `dll.conf`: `smpf`

content of `smpf-samsung.conf`: nothing referring to SCX-3400

content of `xerox_mfp.conf` & `xerox_mfp-smfp.conf`:

```
#Samsung SCX-3400
usb 0x04e8 0x344f
```

Simple Scan detects the scanner but asks for additional drivers (other sane- dependent applications don't even detect the scanner.)

Since `60-libsane.rules` was missing, I manually added it using the content of https://gemfury.com/malept/deb:libsane/-/content/lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules.

it contains

```
# Samsung SCX-3400
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="344f", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"`
```

Still the problem remains.

I guess that is all the important information I can think of right now. Do you have any ideas?
Thanks for your insights and help on the problem.

Best, Lila

Comment: I have posted an answer to a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1262946). It deals with Ubuntu 20.04 and a device connected through the network, not with a USB cable, however, I think it can still be useful to someone ending up here.

Answer (score 0):

I found your question while looking at how to use the SCY-3450W scanner on Ubuntu 18.10. On my device, the printer was configured correctly over the WPS function of WLAN. Simple scan did not find the scanner over Wifi, but did find it when I plugged the printer through USB.

When running the sane-find-scanner command, I got, among other things, the following output:

found USB scanner (vendor=0x04e8 [Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd.], product=0x344f [SCX-3400 Series]) at libusb:001:004

I am not sure it helps, but at least I can reassure you by telling that it's still *supposed* to work.

Best,
François-Xavier