# Ubuntu 20.04 Network printer works but scanner not detected

Tags: 20.04, printing, scanner, samsung

Samsung SCX-3405W Laster Multifunction Printer On Ubuntu 20.04.
The printer works but scanner is not detected by Document Scanner (simple-scan).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*I am answering my own question (which is similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258462/ubuntu-20-04-simple-scan-does-not-detect-scanner))*

In order to make your **Samsung SCX-3405W** network printer print and scan, follow these steps:

## ;tldr

Install the Linux driver from hp.com and add `tcp <printer ip> <port>` to `xerox_mfp.conf`

## FIND & DOWNLOAD THE LINUX DRIVER FOR SCX-3405W

- visit https://support.hp.com/gb-en/drivers/printers
- look for `SCX-3405W`
- change OS to `Linux` and `Ubuntu`
- download the `basic drivers`
- the filename should be something like `uld_V1.00.39_01.17.tar.gz`

## UNPACK & INSTALL THE DRIVERS

- tar -zxvf uld_V1.00.39_01.17.tar.gz
- cd uld
- sudo ./install.sh

## ADD THE PRINTER AT THE CUPS ADMIN PAGE

- go to http://localhost:631/admin
- click `Add Printer`
- Under the `Discovered Network Pritners` there should be multiple options for the Samsung SCX-3400 Series. Choose one and click `Continue`.
- If the `Connection` starts with `ipp://` you have chosen the correct one. In case it does not, go back in your browser and choose another until you find the one with ipp connection. Adjust the name, location, etc. and then click `continue`.
- In the next step review the config and click `Add printer`
- The printer should now be available in the `Settings>Printers`

## PRINTING TEST PAGE

- Go to `Settings > Printers`
- Click the `gear` icon next to the printer
- Click `Printing options`, set what you want and click `Test page` in the upper left corner. It should print a page.

## CHECK IF SCANNER WORKS

- Open Document Scanner and see if it finds your scanner.

## IF SCANNER IS NOT DETECTED

- Find the IP of your printer in the `Settings > Printers > Your printer > Gear icon > Printer details`
- Edit this config `sudo nano /etc/sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf` and add the following lines (I found this tip here: http://www.sane-project.org/man/sane-xerox_mfp.5.html):

  ```
  # Samsung SCX-3405W, network mode
  # tcp HOST_ADDR PORT
  tcp <ip.of.your.printer> 9400
  ```
- Log out & Log in (not sure if this is necessary)
- The scanner should now be detected.

Even after all this, the simple-scan seems to be very slow in scanning. Much slower than on to what I was used to on Ubuntu 16.04. Will investigate.

Comment: My printer exactly. Your instructions worked like a charm. Thank you so much for saving me tons of time! :) Scanning is very slow for me too, though. Or, to be more exact: Displaying the scanned document in Simple Scan is super slow. Used to be 2-3x as fast in Ubuntu 14.04. Fortunately, the printer itself is still as quick as it used to be. :)

Comment: Exactly my problem with Simple Scan, unfortunately I have not been able to resolve it quickly and now I do not have time to investigate. In case you find something, please let me know, thx.

Comment: It seems I have found the solution to the slow scanning on this forum https://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/forum/index.php?topic=352.0. I just had to install `sudo apt install libusb-0.1-4` even though the `libusb-1.0.0` was already installed. Scanning is now fast.

Comment: In case your printer is on a network you may want to check out the Network mode alternative at https://gist.github.com/Jiab77/553f6c34af38578b311a8360f6de832c by adding `tcp IP [port]` at the appropriate printer section in `/etc/sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to present an alternative way to detect the scanner which worked for me (under Linux Mint 20.1 Cinnamon) without loosing speed during the scaning :
The installation of libusb might be required to detect the scanner in the network (Source https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Samsung-Laserdrucker/):

*sudo apt install libusb-0.1-4*

*sudo scanimage -L*

After this, the scanner should be detected, al least it worked in my case.